# Connect/Send information from android phone to other phone without server/wifi or bluetooth (game)

Tags: android, multiplayer

I want to develope an Android App where a user(A) can challenge another user(B).
If B accept the challenge, the game will need to synchronise a timer.
In the end the results will be send to each other.

Is there a possibilty to realize that when both phones are just connected to the internet but without wifi/bluetooth or an extern server?
There is no problem if Player A hosts a little server just for the game on his phone if thats possible

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I would rather you using a Peer-to-Peer system, but hosting a server on a player would also make sense.

Comment: Do you have some links for tutorials or discriptions? :)

Comment: [Example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html) from the Android API documentation